# How to add custom class processing functionality in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dll

I'm a little new to Qt. I have been programming in C++ for quite a while.

I want to create an application in Qt/C++ just because it's very easy to create the GUIs. I wanted to know that is it possible that I can write a C++ class in native C++ and use it in my Qt application.

I want to write the GUI in Qt and do all processing using my native C++ code rather than Qt/C++. Is it possible to compile a DLL in native C++ and then load and use it in QtC++ application?

I really want to write a GUI application using C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "native C++" as opposed to "Qt/C++", so the question makes little sense. All of core Qt code is compiled native C++, just as any C++ application that uses Qt is.

As [JBentley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227469/jbentley) has duly noted:

> [You may be] confused because of the code generating tools Qt uses, like moc [or uic]. Those don't mean that C++ compiles natively while Qt doesn't. All those tools do is provide a convenient way to produce a lot of boiler code that the framework relies on, so that the programmer can pretend they don't exist and use things like Qt's slots and signals. The final code which you compile and link is ordinary C++, with calls into the Qt library (also C++) which you've used.

If what you're asking is "am I forced to use Qt classes in all parts of my application", then no - nobody's forcing you to do that. If you already have parts of your application written using boost, or standard C++ library classes, it's fine.

You have to understand that Qt has modular design and provides a lot of non-GUI functionality. You can use the non-gui modules in the non-gui part of your code. It's a fairly clean and general purpose application development framework. It's perfectly fine to use it for various internet server applications, for example.

The following Qt modules are of note for non-gui development:

- [Core](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-index.html): Core non-graphical classes: containers, event loop, timers, threads, state machines, internationalization, XML, json, file I/O - all of it portable.
- [Network](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html): Classes to make network programming easier and more portable. Includes secure sockets, HTTP requests, etc.
- [SQL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsql-index.html): Classes for database integration using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use any C++ code you would like. I have have actually had questions with the same thought process in my day to day work. First you need to grok the idea that Qt uses normal C++ and special tools to create a robust set of libraries.

Later on come back and you will want to learn more about the items below:

- **Signals and Slots**

  - This is how events are wired together.
  - One objects sends a signal and all connected slots get called with the given parameters.
  - Signals and slots are an example of the Observer Pattern.
- **Designer Forms**

  - The form designer lets you lay out controls using simple drag and drop operations.
  - The .ui file gets transformed into C++ code as part of the build process.
- **Layouts**

  - You can do a lot of things with just the horizontal, vertical and grid layouts
- **Spacers**

  - You can push things up, down, left, or right using different types of spacers
  - They look like a spring on the form designer.
- **Resource Files**

  - Lets you embed graphics and other content directly into the application.
- **Models, Views and Delegates**

  - Hard to avoid if your have a non trivial UI

There are other things too, but knowledge in these areas will let you make some decent desktop applications. My favorite reference is older, but still a goodie: "C++ GUI Programming with Qt4" [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Edition-Prentice-Software-Development/dp/0132354160](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160)

Yes QT4 is "old" and QT5 has been out for some time... but the book provides a solid foundation that you will be able to add information to.